# Is it possible to install Mercurial 1.9 on 9.10?

Tags: 9.10, mercurial

So I have an old server which I want to use as Mercurial repository host. `apt-get install mercurial` gives me v0.9, which is stoneage and without Windows filename workaround, which I rely on.

I've downloaded the v1.9 source and tried to build it but I end up in a web of depedency conflicts. Is it any way I can get v1.9 of mercurial to run in an Intrepid installation (kernel  2.6.24-19-generic)?

If not, how about 1.1 (the first one with Windows filename workaround)?

Comment: You'll likely need to upgrade or satisfy all the dependencies. Karmic has been EOL'd since April

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Nada.

First, 9.10 has reached its "EOL", or "End Of Life" - you'd be better off installing 10.04 or 8.04, they're still supported.

With that being said, you *could* try to enable the backports repository - ([more on that here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository)) and see if it's got Mercurial 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

I made it! I actually tried to upgrade the release first with do-release-upgrade, but that failed. What did succeed in this process however, was upgrading Python using aptitude (apt-get failed). This lead me to try and compile the source for mercurial agaian, and voila!

So `aptitude install python-dev` did the trick, followed by `make install`

To be honest, I'm not quite sure which apt-sources I used at that moment, but I think it was Hardy. Guess no one else will try this after me anyway, so... well anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get Mercurial 1.9 from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases) for it. To add it, pop open a terminal and type:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases

Once that's completed, run a quick update.

> sudo apt-get update

Then you can now install the latest Mercurial using apt-get.

Comment: It looks like they only have installs for hardy, lucid, maverick, and natty. Not Karmic since it's been EOL'd for a while.

Comment: @Marco Will it not work though? I have used older packages before and such

Comment: These are new packages on older systems. The dependency hell will still exist.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Ah okay, oops.

Comment: `add-apt-repository: command not found` :-P Seems like it was first introduced in Karmic. Oh well... Look's like I'm heading for an upgrade