# Is there any alternative to Workrave in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, workrave

Workrave package had removed from Oneiric, and setting for blocking screen removed from Gnome 3 (it was in keyboard settings in Gnome 2). Is there any alternative to control working time on computer in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Workrave wasn't really removed from Oneiric, but rather waiting on a fix so that it would actually work.  I saw that today it got uploaded into the [Oneiric Backports](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric-backports/workrave).

Make sure you have the backports repository enabled in your software sources, and also make sure that the package list is up-to-date, then you should be able to install/update it again.  (I don't know about integration into gnome 3 though.)

- [How do I enable the "backports" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are [rsibreak](http://www.lcdf.org/%7Eeddietwo/xwrits) and [xwrits](https://userbase.kde.org/RSIBreak). Both available on repos<sup>[[1]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rsibreak)[[2]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xwrits)</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Workrave on 11.10 [via official repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=workrave).

Answer (score 0):

### [Safe Eyes](http://slgobinath.github.io/SafeEyes/)

Available [on repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/safeeyes) and on `pip3`.

> Protect your eyes from eye strain using this continuous breaks
> Safe Eyes is a simple tool to remind you to take periodic breaks for your
> eyes. This is essential for anyone spending more time on the computer to
> avoid eye strain and other physical problems.

### [Stretchly](https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly)

AppImage and deb packages are available on [release page](https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly/releases) ([brew](https://brew.sh/) way doesn't seems to work).

> Stretchly is a cross-platform Electron app that reminds you to take breaks when working on your computer.