# Help with installing and how to confirm successful installation of ClamAV?

Tags: installation, antivirus, clamav

I have just researched and attempted to install ClamAV as an antivirus program on my Ubuntu install using these two articles:

- [Clam AV package download page](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/packages/packages-linux/)
- [How do I install the latest clamav & clamtk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114425/how-do-i-install-the-latest-clamav-clamtk)

These pages seem to indicate that Clam AV ships with Ubuntu 12.04. I was sent to the Ubuntu button by <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and then searched and found software sources. I was told that changing these settings installed Clam AV.

All that was done but I can't find an Icon or some other way of working with the program and doing scans, updating or doing scans as I do in Norton. How do I know it has loaded and is working?

Comment: Clamtk, the gui front-end to clamav, can be found and installed from the software center.

Answer (score 1):

ClamAV is a commandline program. If you want a GUI, install ClamTK. However, you still need ClamAV. ClamTK is a GUI for ClamAV.