# How to compile and install clamav from surceforge?

Tags: clamav

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. I'm affraid I've installed a virus on my computer (I've clicked a link which was a virus), I'd prefere to check if everything is fine.

I've installed clamAV using Synaptic. The installed version was 0.96.5, while the most recent version is 0.97.6. When I was trying to update virus database, I got a warning that the version of clamAV I'm using is outdated. Since I didn't know how to update the software by Synaptic or apt (both show the installed version as the newest) I've uninstalled all and downloaded the recent version from sourceforge. I've unpacked the tar.gz archive, entered the folder but when I type

```
./configure
```

I'm getting the message:

```
configure: error: Please install zlib and zlib-devel packages
```

When I type

```
sudo aptitude install zlib zlib-devel
```

The terminal output says there is no such packages (there is no package zlib-devel and there is many packages which name contain zlib).

I suppose the link contained probably the Windows virus, but I'd prefere to make sure there is nothing in my computer. As well as I'm not sure if the virus, even without harming my system, can send itself to my e-mail contacts or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for solution, I've followed the thread [How do I enable the "backports"repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository) and it helped, the recent version of clamAV began accesible through apitiude tools.

Answer (score 0):

**My opinion is to install clamav, from ubuntu packages, with the following:**

```
sudo apt-get install clamav clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam
```

**To update clamav:**

```
sudo freshclam -v
```

**If Updating the Clamav failed with error message try the following:**

**In Terminal:**

**Stop the updater:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop
```

**Update**:

```
sudo freshclam -v
```

**Start the updater:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start
```

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/19931-ubuntu-1204-clamav-problem-with-updating

Answer (score 0):

I could not install clamav as package, because I need to compile it for Zimbra.
So I found a solution:

You must install `zlib1g-dev` package. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```