# Building webkit from source

Tags: 12.04, application-development, programming, gcc, webkit

I tried to install the webkit applicaion from sources using this manual:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit

When I type:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

the following error occurs:

```
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
configure: error: Compiler GCC >= 4.7 or Clang >= 3.0 is required for C++ compilation
```

When I type:

```
gcc --version
```

It responds:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-11precise2) 4.7.2
```

Hence the error does not concern gcc version. Why the execution fails?

**Edited:** Previous problem is solved by updating g++ to 4.7. But the following error occurs further:

```
checking for GAIL... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gail-3.0 >= 3.0) were not met:

No package 'gail-3.0' found 

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GAIL_CFLAGS
and GAIL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have apt-get install gail-3.0, but the error remains.

**Edited:**
Also did:

```
apt-get install gail-3.0-dev
apt-get build-dep webkit
```

But further missing packages revealed:
    error: Package requirements (libsoup-2.4 >= 2.40.0) were not met:

```
Requested 'libsoup-2.4 >= 2.40.0' but version of libsoup is 2.38.1

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBSOUP_CFLAGS
and LIBSOUP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Comment: My guess is your G++ is older than your gcc

Comment: you are right!!

Comment: will 

    sudo apt-get install g++-4.7 

be enough?

Comment: might be.  try it and see.

Comment: Didn`t work, probably because g++-4.7 is not set default. How to do that?

Comment: look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version

Comment: worked, but further errors occur: configure: error: Package requirements (gail-3.0 >= 3.0) were not met:

No package 'gail-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GAIL_CFLAGS
and GAIL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Comment: i sudo apt-get install gail-3.0, but dont know how to adjust the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

Comment: apt-get install gail-3.0-dev.  Why don't you just apt-get build-dep whatever package contains webkit instead of fighting with this?

Comment: Additional note, evidently you didn't follow the Get dependencies directions.

Comment: Agreed with @AbrahamVanHelpsing.  Please read through the help document you linked to, it gives you a list of what to do, including what you need to install.

Comment: Guys, guys, why don't you continue this in a chat? Also see [How do I enable the "backports" repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository), [Install packages from newer release without building (apt pinning)](http://askubuntu.com/q/103320/17789) and [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Links were not useful to me. Either already did or could not adapt to my situation.

Answer (score 4):

The PPA mentioned in the question is greatly outdated for 12.04 hence you have to disable it and find another instructions on building webkit from source. Additionally, someone has to edit the wiki.

Looks like webkit is now in `libwebkitgtk-3.0-0`. Try these:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
apt-get source libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
cd webkit-*
dpkg-buildpackage
```

I'll edit the wiki if it works.