# Drivers for Linux Distros

Tags: drivers, 14.10, lenovo

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 on a Lenovo T540 laptop.

In addition to information about how to update and maintain the drivers for this laptop I would like general information about how to update this laptop's drivers on any version of Ubuntu (if it differs). Perhaps there's a repo for this? I didn't see anything like this after a few Google searches, and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/i-want-to-download-all-reqiured-ubuntu-drivers) command doesn't display anything when I run it and I'm still having issues.

It would be helpful to get any information on how to generally go about updating any computer's driver running Ubuntu.

Finally, it would be helpful to get information about generally how to go about updating any computer's drivers running any distro of Linux.

Also, I appreciate stability and reliability would it be better to run 14.04 LTS for these purposes?

These questions: Newb and all that.

Comment: the "duplicate" question does not have an accepted answer and it does not clear up the idea that other users might think there are different steps to be taken to get the drivers for their computer. Also, the command given in the top answer of the "duplicate" post doesn't give me any output and I am still having driver issues.

Comment: Sometimes you have to wait 2-3 minutes for the command to execute, so that it can scan all your hardware, and then you'll get output. Or maybe it hasn't found any proprietary graphics drivers, so your operating system is using the built-in default open source graphics driver.

Comment: I did wait, still nothing. I think the problem might have been that I ran it while booting from a Live-boot ISO. Sorry for the confusion, but I stand by everything else I said in my previous comment. Would it still count as a duplicate? I'm thinking that it could help people who might think the same thing and help correct it.

Comment: Please visit this chat room: [Room for karel and GoProCameraByGoPro](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20251/room-for-karel-and-goprocamerabygopro) where we can discuss these questions at length.

Comment: No response in the chat room, please unmark my question as a duplicate. I also can't comment in the other question to get more information from anyone... I still need more information abou this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Device drivers in linux are written as kernel modules.  Typically if there are updates for special drivers (nvidia like drivers come to mind) you may be able to get binary files and an installation script for your architecture.  Otherwise, you will likely get any driver changes (if there were any) when you install kernel updates.

If there are special changes for your specific model sometimes you can find kernel patches.  This would be a bit more involved as you would likely end up compiling the kernel then installing the newly compiled version of the kernel.