# Nvidia Corporation: G96 [GeForce 9500 GT]

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

After I recently updated my computer software "Ubuntu" I went to my "System Settings" And click on "Software And Updates" There was something new I have never seen before.

**Nvidia Corporation: G96 [GeForce 9500 GT]**
Below There are 5 Options.

**1.** "Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.76 from nvidia-340 (proprietary, tested)"

**2.** "Using NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.125 from nvidia-304-updates (proprietary)"

**3.** "Using NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.125 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)"

**4.** "Using X.Org X server - Nouveau disaplay driver from xsever-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)"

**5.** "Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.76
 from nvidia-340-updates (proprietary)

I really don't know what these mean so if you do please tell me withc one to choose.

Theres one more also, below the options,

**Unknown: Unknown This device is not working.**

**1.** "Using Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPU's from amd64-microcode (proprietary)

**2.** Do not use this device

So I have no clue on what these are if you have any info or idea on witch one i should use, Please Tell me Thanks!

**System Info**

Processor **AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1090T Processor × 6**

Graphics **GeForce 9500 GT/PCIe/SSE2**

OS type **64-bit**

Disk **968.0 GB**

**Ubuntu 15.04**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers).  From the answer: *The output of the command `ubuntu-drivers devices` will be a list of the package names and short descriptions of the available drivers and it will also identify the **Recommended** proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver for your system.*

Answer (score 0):

These are options to install proprietary drivers. With this Nvidia card and if you are new to Ubuntu, I would no suggest installing any of proprietary Nvidia drivers. There is no guarantee that the system boots up normally after that. I know that nvidia-173 works well with this card, but I am not sure that even 304 will work. Now you use open source drivers. And if everything works OK, then it makes no much sense to change anything.

But if you choose to test if proprietary drivers work better, or work at all with this card, then you need to know how to revert system back. It can be done using system console with a command

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

But for a new user it is not always easy to reach the console.

The AMD microcode updater is a driver, which loads microcode to your CPU. I think it is quite safe to enable it.

Comment: Sorry I think i know wt your saying but not all of it, Explain it more in detail if you can thanks