# 15.04 Can't install GUI driver

Tags: gui, 15.04, nouveau

For some reason 15.04 can't install GUI. Even when simply trying to boot with a stick I am getting Nouveau error. Basically can't identify chip on my GTX980. Very strange because 14.04.2 have no problem with new Maxwell Nvidia Chipset.

I mean I guess I can use alternative to install but I wonder what is going on 15 is > than 14 .... so in theory stuff should work better on 15 ....

I'll roll with 14.04.2 for now but I am uneasy with having not latest and greatest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)