# What drivers do I need for Acer Aspire E5-571 laptop?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, acer

I want to install Ubuntu 15.04 on my new laptop Acer Aspire E5-571.

So how can I get all required drivers for my laptop? I am asking all my friends to help me.

I am going to use Ubuntu first time and I do not have any experience regarding fresh install of Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you do not need any additional drivers to run Ubuntu.

You can test how Ubuntu works with your hardware by booting from LiveCD and trying Ubuntu without install.

If you have more specific questions, you are welcome to ask.

I suggest installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for a first-time user. It is more stable and support is for 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu requires no additional drivers generally. If you are having dual Graphics Card then supported proprietary drivers are easily available from **Additional Drivers** application from the menu.

[image]