# Do I have any graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia

[Here's a picture of my drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifU9l.png)

> 04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce
>   GTX 650] (rev a1)     Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK107 [GeForce GTX
>   650]  Kernel driver in use: nouveau

I don't see any graphics drivers. I have a GeForce GTX 650 graphics card.

Is this a common problem? Please help me, I need different drivers to install Steam.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Nvidia drivers by this terminal command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-361
```

You need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS if you are using UEFI.

It must be some glitch that the driver is not displayed in GUI.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-361

Comment: Are you connected to internet? Run `sudo apt update` first.