# Ubuntu and gaming PC

Tags: nvidia, games, 17.04

So I just ordered hardware to build my first gaming PC, I'm going to use ubuntu as the main OS for gaming and was wondering if I'll need specific drivers to use my MSI GTX 1070.

Comment: You should be fine with the stock drivers, but you can also install the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

A very quick search on the nvidia website shows Linux 64-bit drivers for a GeForce 1070. Gaming on Ubuntu is going to be limited compared to windows, you might want to dual boot depending on which games you are planning on playing.