# Am I in Software Rendering Mode?

Tags: 16.04, graphics

My Ubuntu 16 installation occasionally has weird rendering issues. How can I tell if I am in software rendering mode?

Running `ubuntu-drivers devices` outputs:

```
== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free
```

Comment: What are the results of running the command: `ubuntu-drivers devices` ?

Comment: @karel `== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operating system is not using an Nvidia or AMD proprietary graphics driver, so your system is currently running in software rendering mode. If there was a proprietary graphics driver compatible with your computer's hardware available from the default Ubuntu repositories, then `ubuntu-drivers devices` would have listed it.

For more information read the answers to [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers).