# Ubuntu - system working a slow and low fps on animations. Why?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10

I have 3 gigabytes of RAM and intel core 2 duo 2.5 GHz of CPU.

I just deleted my windows 8.1 operating system and installed Ubuntu.

The problem is, I have fps drops on animations and it is sometimes really slow when using youtube etc.

I want a smooth experience of Ubuntu. What can I do?

(I have installed the drivers with the Ubuntu install)

Comment: Nvidia GPUs work better with a proprietary driver installed. Search for Additional Drivers in the menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) and [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Comment: Nope, I deleted Ubuntu and re-installed it with the drivers of it, also downloaded Nvidia drivers for my graphics card.