# Is my Graphic card supported by Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, nvidia-geforce

I am looking for more information about my graphics card whether it will support Ubuntu or not. I have GeForce GT 640_(https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt640). I would really appreciate any information could be provided by the community.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [this](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk) page, where you can download official drivers.
This indicates that your  GT 460 is compatible.

Comment: Thank you. It seems it does support. Hopefully, it will work when I install it as well.