# I'm confused about Secure Boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm new to Linux.

While I want to install Ubuntu 18.04, there is an option that if you want to install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hard and additional media features. I chose that option and I need turn off Secure Boot and put the password there. I put it and continue Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

So, I'm confused because, after installation, I opened Software & Updates, went to Additional Drivers and no additional drivers were installed. So, is it that Secure Boot is not turned off yet?

Please teach me how to install the drivers.

This is the spec of my laptop;
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU (2.50 GHz - 2.70 GHz)
System Memory: 8GB RAM
Graphic Device (1): AMD Radeon R5 M330 2GB
Graphic Device (2): Intel(R) HD Graphics 620
Storage: 1TB HDD

Comment: The option will allow you to install additional drivers *if available*. Your laptop may be so straightforward that no additional drivers are necessary, so the installation system does not offer you to install them. In other words, what drivers do you think you are missing?

Comment: You don't need to install drivers. Usually Ubuntu installs required drivers for you.

Comment: and did you update the system? add.drivers only show up after the update

Comment: But my laptop doesn't have any drivers. Ubuntu doesn't installs it.

Comment: Well yes, I actually update the system. But, after the update, still, doesn't have any drivers.

Comment: Did your laptop/OS tell you anything about missing drivers?

Comment: How did you turn off secure boot?

Comment: If no "additional drivers" are shown then you probably don't need any *extra* drivers that aren't open source.  What makes you think you need more drivers?

Comment: @NafizAdly Ubuntu's Additional Drivers tool will only show you additional drivers if there's any that are available for your hardware.  Unless something is not working properly, the Additional Drivers tool showing you that you don't need any additional drivers **is a good thing**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Comment: If graphics, sound, wifi, bluetooth etc. works properly then Ubuntu already installed all necessary drivers.

Comment: @karel: It looks like OP wants to know more about the relation between Secure Boot and (additional) drivers.

Comment: In the question it says *Please teach me how to install the drivers.* so that's also a legitimate part of this question.