# About Graphics Driver Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, lts

My device is Asus X550LN
Intel® Core™ i3-4010U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 
GeForce 840M/PCIe/SSE2

Now i have installed nVidia Geforce 840m driver. should i need to install Intel graphics driver also ? If needed then how to install intel driver ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers) *If your computer has an Intel processor and it doesn't have a discrete graphics processor, then `ubuntu-drivers devices` will not return results that show that a proprietary graphics card driver is available to be installed.* ... because the Intel graphics driver is built-in in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you be using Intel Graphics for things that are of importance to you? If so, then go for it. To me, you'll be fine with your main graphics card. Intel graphics should be fine with the already included drivers in the Linux kernel. At least I haven't had any issues with mine for the time I have had on Ubuntu.