# Ubuntu Studio Nvidia drivers compatibility

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, ubuntu-studio

I am currently using Mint on a machine that is configured as an audio workstation although it also does a wide variety of other tasks.

I am thinking of trying Ubuntu Studio instead.

I have read that Ubuntu Studio uses the stock linux-lowlatency kernel. I have found this kernel to be incompatible with nvidia drivers when used on Mint. (I am using the liquorix kernel)

So my question is - does Ubuntu Studio work well and easily with Nvidia drivers or are there many hoops to jump through?

Does it update without breaking nvidia drivers? Does it require driver installation that is more complex than the process for installing other software?

EDIT this post is not answered by [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers) as it doesn't address Ubuntu Studio and the low-latency kernel specifically. I have already found the low latency kernel to be incompatible with nvidia drivers when used in Mint so I'm asking if that is different in Ubuntu Studio.

EDIT please note I am NOT asking about compatibility with regular Ubuntu - I am asking about Ubuntu Studio and whichever lowlatency kernel it uses by default. Regular Ubuntu does not use a lowlatency kernel by default.

Answer (score 1):

I have now tested Ubuntu Studio and can confirm that the included lowlatency kernel 4.15 works with the nvidia drivers.

Loads of special features of Ubuntu Studio totally didn't work - but the graphics did.

However the ubuntu studio **installer** and live usb stick does not work with an nvidia card, I had to install with my monitor plugged into my mobo's graphics and swap it after I had installed and installed the nvidia driver.

This was NOT my experience on Mint, where i couldn't get the lowlatency kernel to work with nvidia. When trying to solve that I found a number of peoples saying it is incompatible. I now think they are wrong, but don't know what my original problem on Mint actually was. (probably DKMS)

Comment: Your issue with the installer is likely to be fixed with 19.10 releasing in October.

Answer (score 0):

The entire reason the lowlatency kernel exists (as opposed to the RT kernel of yore) is twofold:

1. The lowlatency kernel is less likely to be compromised by an attacker taking control via a realtime permissions, thereby locking out the rest of the system. Lowlatency kernels allow the user to continue to interact with the system while providing the lowest latency possible to processes requiring realtime access.
2. It is easier to maintain than RT or realtime kernels, and is therefore guaranteed to have the same driver compatibility as the generic kernel included with other Ubuntu flavors.

So, your question is most likely answered with point #2 above.