# NVidia Drivers 340 or 390, which one should I choose?

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

I'm getting two options for NVidia Drivers 340 and 390.
I was wondering, what are the differences between the 3.40 and 3.90 driver and which one should I choose ?

My Video Card is Asus NVidia GTX 760

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: NVidia GTX 760. Both version support that card

Comment: ...there is no version 3.90/3.40. :~)

Comment: Updated driver search by nVidia model, do not download, just check correct driver version
http://www.geforce.com/drivers Why are you seeing those versions. It looks like card is newer and can use newer drivers. What version of Ubuntu and have you added ppa for most current versions? https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers If you install incorrect driver or want to change, be sure to purge as newer driver will create conflicts if older not removed first.

Comment: Yes thanks. It seems 3.90 was the recommended by the ubuntu PPA, after changing to the nvidia ppa the recommended driver was 430.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

You can check for recommended versions from below official website.

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

Each new version comes with new functionality or bug fix so stick with new one.

For details and differences  between each drivers, please refer the change logs.

Follow the below ppa guidelines to install that.

https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I had the same question.

The NVidia driver *README* is here (very extensive indeed):

http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/510.68.02/README/index.html

In *Appendix A* ("Supported NVIDIA GPU Products"):

http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/510.68.02/README/supportedchips.html

we find the list of all NVidia products listed either as "current", in which case they are supported by the "latest" driver release (currently 510) or by a "legacy release".

"Legacy releases" are currently

- 470.xx driver
- 390.xx driver
- 367.xx driver
- 340.xx driver
- 304.xx driver
- 173.14.xx driver
- 96.43.xx driver
- 71.86.xx driver

The command `lspci -vnn | grep -i NVIDIA | grep VGA` should give information about your card, in particular, in my case the PCI code (e.g. `[10de:1c82]`) indicates that this is an NVIDIA product (`10de`), namely a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (`1c82`).

In the present case, the `NVidia GTX 760` is no longer listed under the latest/current driver but under the 470.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply go to Sotware Updater >settings and lifepatch > additional drivers and intall nvidia-driver-435 , works like a charm !