# Ubuntu installation advice needed

Tags: system-installation

My question is about ubuntu compatibilty with my hardware.
I have an assembeled pc with the following specs:

1. i7 2700 processor
2. 16 gb ram
3. 240 gb ssd
4. 1tb hdd
5. Nvidia 730 4 gb graphics

I wanted to ask if its a good idea to install ubuntu on this system and also what precautions should i take while installing drivers for graphics card?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/)

Comment: You mean the NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 ? See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJSXOSXjkUo  and https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/76396/en-us

Comment: Your i7 is an early UEFI system. IF UEFI updated from vendor it should be ok in UEFI boot mode. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI And you will need nVidia driver installed, but probably need nomodeset to boot live installer & first boot of install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it