# Additional Drivers utility

Tags: software-installation, additional-drivers

Do I need to plug in the bootable USB drive when using the Additional Drivers Utility in Ubuntu 19.10? "No Network Adapter Found" in my previous question. "How do use Additional Drivers Utility" in this question.

Comment: No. The LiveUSB software repository contains only the software required to install your system, and nothing more.

Comment: I'm trying to install wi-fi drivers for my iMac. Do I need to wire connect my iMac to use the Additional Drivers Utility?

Comment: Yes. Additional Drivers needs access to the online Ubuntu repositories. If the LiveUSB had wireless access, then you probably have the correct driver installed already.

Comment: I'm confused. I installed the Ubuntu 19.10. No network adapter found. I'm trying to find the wi-fi driver from the Additional Drivers Utility. So, "if I do not need the LiveUSB, are the drivers already on my iMac"? Besides, what do you mean "if the LiveUSB had wireless access, then probably have the correct driver installed"? I do not have wi-fi driver. Can I install additional drivers, then setup the wi-fi?

Comment: If your Mac's wireless is not working, you should ask about that (by deleting this question and starting a new question). Drivers are only one possibility among several. If you are sure that your drivers are the problem, then please edit your question to show your troubleshooting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Broadcom wireless drivers offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626642/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-offline)

Comment: Re-edited this question in order to remove the rude and abusive flag which was caused by repeated violations of the terms of service. Your question also got bumped into duplicate question review by the same unlucky edit. If you roll the edit back this question will probably get flagged by the same flag again.

Comment: @karel It was bumped to a dupe by me. If the driver is there, that means it is a Broadcom device. So there is a Q&A about offline driver installation.

Comment: This question has a history that I keep asking the OP to clarify it, the OP replies in a comment, I edit the question and add the information that was posted in that comment, and then the OP deletes his comments and removes my edits. So it basically has not been possible to get a lock on what's being asked by this question because it keeps being changed. This is my last try to fix things, after this I give up.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to plug in a bootable USB when using the Additional Drivers utility. All you need is a working internet connection in case you want to [install a driver](https://askubuntu.com/q/543325/). In case you can't connect to the internet following the instructions in [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974/) and [My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/235279/).

Comment: The problem is. I'm trying to find a wi-fi driver through the Additional Drivers Utility. I cannot connect to the Internet.

Comment: @karel I've seen somewhere a way how to properly mount LiveUSB a way that it is recognized as a repo. It actually contains all "additional drivers" in `pool` derectory. It works out-of-the-box only from a CD or DVD. But I don't remember how to do that.