# Graphic drivers are not working, how do you install new ones?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I was trying to install new drivers for my AMD Radeon R7 240 graphics card, but when I rebooted my computer (OS Ubuntu 18.04) it seems like the drivers don't work and I can't really access the computer other than a terminal window.

I have tried to boot in safe mode but it doesn't seem to work, so I was wondering if there is any way that I can install the drivers via the terminal?

Comment: The question is unclear. What is your OS? What drivers you are asking about? What is "your graphics card"?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and a AMD Radeon graphics card.

Comment: What is the card model and what are the drivers?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be answerable. [ask]

Comment: It's a Radeon R7 240, not sure about the drivers, all I know is that they are not working.

Comment: So you installed something that is not working... I can suggest removing that something.

Comment: Where did you get the drivers and how did you install them?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any idea how to do that or how to install new drivers

Comment: I downloaded a tar.gz file from the AMD website, and then followed instructions on how to install the drivers (with terminal)

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of this important information. Do not bury it in comments.

Comment: So follow instructions to uninstall them. But first I would suggest to disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings. Most likely the driver will work.

Comment: Take a look to [`ubuntu-drivers`](https://askubuntu.com/a/543329/349837) (`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`). Would be great if you edit your question adding the output of `inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635.

First, you should update your system with `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade; sudo reboot`. After reboot, you should check if AMDGPU-PRO Driver package is already installed on your system with `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro`. Then, download your specific amd driver with `wget --referer=https://www.amd.com https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz`, extract its contents with `tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz` and enter in the driver directory with `cd amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563-ubuntu-18.04`. Finally, you could install it with `./amdgpu-pro-install -y; sudo reboot`

Make sure you are a member of the video group with `groups` command and, if you are not yet in that group, just add yourself with `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME`.

If anything goes wrong, you can remove AMDGPU-PRO driver with `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`.

That's it.

If this answer don't work, consider reformulating your question with the exact steps that you made before getting to your current point.

---

Here is a overview of all commands typed above for preparing your distro, downloading your specific driver and installing it.

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade; sudo reboot
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
wget --referer=https://www.amd.com https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/linux/amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz
cd amdgpu-pro-19.30-934563-ubuntu-18.04
/amdgpu-pro-install -y; sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry apparently the below won't work for AMD devices, I'll leave it here as it could help with other connected devices.

You can run `ubuntu-drivers list` to show all drivers available for your hardware.

If the list looks right, you can run `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` to install them automatically. Or to install  individually listed drivers run `sudo apt install <driver>`

Comment: Nothing shows up when I run the "ubuntu-drivers list" command

Comment: This is not applicable to AMD devices.