# Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 only boot in recovery/safe mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, gpu-driver

Problem:

- I dual booted Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5QyjHIYwT
- For 2-3 days, I was able to boot into Ubuntu 18.04 (default) or Windows 10 as needed. The GRUB screen gave me the option of which OS to choose from. Everything worked perfectly.
- Today I booted Ubuntu, coded for a bit and then restarted the system to boot into Windows 10.
- The blue windows appear (as do the circular loading dots) but the system hangs on a black screen.
- Restarting the system to enter Ubuntu again, I find that the system hangs on a purple screen.

Ubuntu 18.04 info:

- Only loads from recovery mode (only Linux 5.0.0-23-generic works and not 5.0.0-37)
- Using UEFI
- Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-drive-435 (proprietary, tested) – recommended driver

Windows 10 info:

- Only loads in safe mode (with networking or without).
- Using UEFI

Points of interested:

- If I switch the 435 driver to ‘nvidia-driver-430 (proprietary)’, then even recovery mode doesn’t boot. In order to boot with 430, I had to do the following:
  1) Press ‘e’ at the GRUB menu before selecting ‘Ubuntu’
  2) Add the following to the line that starts with ‘Linux’: ‘acpi=off’

  Note: If I added ‘nomodeset’ Ubuntu still wouldn’t load.
- System specifications: 1) CPU = AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 2) Graphics Card = EVGA Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 TI Ultra Gaming Edition 3) MB = Asus PRIME X570-P

Note that I’m a novice Ubuntu user, so I’d really appreciate pretty streamlined instructions (as painful as that may be!). Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I decided which driver to use by going to Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers -> Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-435 (proprietary, tested)

EDIT 2:
The problem appears to be driver related. Here is a temporary fix: Open Windows 10 in safe mode, uninstall Nvidia display driver, restart and I can open Windows 10 normally. I then run Nvidia GeForce Experience and install the same driver again (the most updated one). Then, Ubuntu also boots normally. However, I've been able to replicate the problem (sometimes) with the following sequence:
Computer turned off -> Load Ubuntu -> Restart -> Load Windows -> Shut down -> Load Ubuntu -> Restart -> Load Windows (now hangs on black screen) -> Restart -> Load Ubuntu (now hangs on purple screen).

This seems like a convoluted sequence of a events, but it's what triggered the issue twice. I also triggered it once in another way, but I can't recall the sequence exactly. It involved going between Ubuntu and Windows multiple times though.

Any thoughts to resolve this? I notice that I get a few error messages before Ubuntu hangs for the first time. I check the boot log, but I can't find the messages I saw. Is there any way to find the error messages that can appear before the Ubuntu log in? (The log would only be 3-4 lines long).

Comment: How did you decide which Nvidia graphics driver to install? In Ubuntu 18.04 the correct Nvidia driver for your computer's hardware is selected and installed automatically: https://askubuntu.com/a/543329

Comment: Do you have latest UEFI from Asus? AMD in July put out updates for Ryzen 3000 only for 19.10 support and then vendors have to roll it out with UEFI update for their systems.https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3000-BIOS-Update-Good  Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. Often issue is Windows turned fast start up back on with an update or it needs chkdsk. Grub only boots working Windows.

Comment: Hi karel. I edited my question to explain how I decided which driver to use. Should I be following the procedure in the link you sent? I got both operating systems to boot normally by doing something strange. I ran Windows in safe mode and deleted the NVIDIA display drivers. Then Windows was able to boot normally. I then installed Nvidia Geforce Experience and from there installed the new drivers. Then somehow Ubuntu now boots normally. I had no idea that the drivers in one partition can affect the other partition. Should I still be installing new drivers on Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi oldfred. My Asus X570-P is on version 1201 (released Sep 12, 2019). There is indeed a newer version (1405 - released Nov 26). It doesn't mention anything regarding Ubuntu though. Also, after uninstalling and reinstalling nvidia drivers on windows 10 (in safe mode), Ubuntu and Windows now boot up normally, which is so odd to me. But is it safe to assume that this has nothing to do with my UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick solution for my system with dual booted Ubuntu 20.04  and Windows 10. I could start the ubuntu (system hangs) only in safe mode but could start windows normally.
I am not sure how it was connected, but when I **uninstalled the just installed a graphic software in windows**, I could start the ubuntu in the normal mode.

Comment: This also worked for me (as I outlined in Edit 2); however, if one wishes to go between each OS often, this really isn't a solution (particularly if you have multiple monitors and use graphics heavy software on Windows). In the end, I sadly deleted Ubuntu. Hopefully, a solid fix can be established in the near future.