# Black screen with lines and dots when installing using NVIDIA 2070 Super

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (on a bootable USB; after I select "Install Ubuntu" in the GRUB boot loader), the screen turns black for a few seconds, then lines and dots appear on the screen. In the top area, there are 2 lines (multi-colored), and at the bottom there are a bunch of dots, as if there was a black piece of paper covering the screen but I poked a bunch of (small) holes though the paper.

I'm using a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 Super.

I have tried the following with no success:

- Using a different USB port
- Using a different USB bootable drive creator (Rufus v3.9 and balenaEtcher v1.5.80)
- Using a different USB
- Re-downloading the ISO (from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Does anyone know what is happening? Also, I have Windows 10 installed on the same disk, maybe that has something to do with it?

[Here](https://youtu.be/JhswFABilj4) is a video of what I am doing.

Comment: Can you specify the video card you use? I think @karel suggestion may help you to at least install the system. But you will need to find some more information on video card in order to use it properly.

Comment: The GPU I am using is the 2070 Super.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solve this situation. Firstly [I use `nomodeset`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do) and then install and open Linux. After this, open a `terminal` and write this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo apt update
```

and then open **Software & Updates** -> **Additional Driver** then select you wanted to use which graphic drivers and apply. Then restart pc. I solve it this way.

[Reference link](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/01/31/install-nvidia-390-25-ubuntu-17-10-18-04/) (for driver install).

Comment: See also [`ubuntu-drivers`](https://askubuntu.com/a/543329/349837)

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but from the video it looks like you should try the top option in grub, "try ubuntu" and only install it when it is up and running (the option "install ubuntu" will appear on the desktop).