# Installing additional drivers in kubuntu

Tags: drivers, kubuntu

How can I install additional drivers in kubuntu like in gnome and this screenshot?
[image]

Comment: Which version do you use? I tried kubuntu 20.04 some time ago when it was still in the **daily build** phase,and it had all the proprietary drivers that I wanted(i.e Nvidia and Broadcom Wi-Fi).But if you use an older version , you can use the command ```ubuntu-drivers install``` to install them.

Answer (score 16):

You have to start System Settings (`systemsettings5`) and select Kubuntu Driver Manager application from it.

Note: Kubuntu Driver Manager may be launched from the terminal using `sudo kubuntu-driver-manager` command.

Comment: That didn't work in 22.10 with a Macbook Air for the wifi Broadcom drivers ('Apply changes" stayed grayed out). But [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/543329/925128) did.