# Meaning of message `nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101400000 on channel -1`

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, dmesg

What is the meaning of these messages in `dmesg`?

```
[184608.460680] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101400000 on channel -1 [3fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]                                                                                               
[185208.535291] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101400000 on channel -1 [3fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]                                                                                               
[185808.593951] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101400000 on channel -1 [3fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]                                                                                               
[187008.711644] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101400000 on channel -1 [3fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]                                                                                               
[188808.928580] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101400000 on channel -1 [3fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]                                                                                               
[190009.066819] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101400000 on channel -1 [3fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]                                                                                               
[191209.156346] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101400000 on channel -1 [3fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
```

Is it a hardware or software problem?

Comment: This means that you didn't install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

`nouveau` is an open source driver for some Nvidia video cards. (https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/)

These messages seem to be warnings the driver caught itself trying to read memory addresses out of bounds?

Since it's an open source driver probably produced without official specifications for the hardware, my first guess would be that it's a bug in the driver itself, but I wouldn't rule anything out.

As others noted, in Ubuntu, official Nvidia drivers are also available to use instead. To do this, go to the Software & Updates and on the Additional Drivers tab, choose one of the Nvidia driver (proprietary) options instead of Nouveau.