# I want to know about Ubuntu Drivers

Tags: drivers

I have a question, I have a Lenovo PC, I Want to know if Ubuntu have drivers 100% compatibles

Comment: You can make a bootable USB and try it for yourself. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: I have a Lenovo PC and everything works (includng the fingerprint reader, more or less). This doesn't mean everything but Lenovo is a quite popular brand, so there will be enough programmers who can try to make things work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/q/543325/)

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of different Lenovo computers, there's no way to tell with just this kind of information.

That's like asking "I have a car, and I want to know 100% if this one particular tire works for my car". You either give lots and lots more information about your car (in this case, about your computer) and hope that someone with the exact same car (or computer) can answer your question, or you just take the tire and try to put it on the car (in this case, download Ubuntu and see if it works).

You can download a copy of Ubuntu, flash it onto an USB drive or burn it to a disc, and start your computer straight from the disc. That requires no installation, won't break your existing install, and allows you to verify if all your hardware is detected correctly.

Comment: I have a Lenovo Thinkcentre M900

Comment: Does someone has this same model??