# How do I get similar gaming performance as on Windows?

Tags: games, steam, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I just installed an onl amd 6790 video card.

It is comparable to the broken gtx 580 it replaced. But when playing dota2 the framerate was less than half.

I then loaded up Windows 10 and tried dota2 on the 6970 there. The framerate was triple! I was getting framerates around 90 fps, where on linux I was getting around 30.

Surely something is misconfigured, as the os could not account for such a massive drop.

I did not install the amd proprietary drives on Linux since they said "unmet dependencies", so I just used the open source ones that were already packaged with 20.04. I have read the open source gaming performance is equivalent to proprietary anyways.

So what gives? How can I get somewhat comparable dota2 framerate on Linux as I do on Windows 10?

Comment: Its Dota2....a native Linux game that I have been playing on linux for 6 years now with an Nvidia card.

Comment: AMD does not support my card on Ubuntu 20.04. The latest driver they have released i 14.04

Comment: The open source drivers are already bundled and install on Ubuntu. I have tried them and they are 25% the performance of where they should be.

Comment: You changed to an entirely different architecture for your GPU.  Best practice is to reinstall the operating system with a hardware change.  Did you do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)