# Ubuntu 20.04 NVIDIA Drivers / Crash after Sleep

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, suspend

I'm a young devop's student, and I recently got a GF63 Thin 10SC-003XFR on wich I chose to install Ubuntu 20.04.3. After installing all my classic tools such as SublimeText, arduino IDE, ect... I tried to play a few games, I quicly noticed that there was something wrong because this pc was not supposed to be so slow on such light games as CS:S so I found out that I was running on the CPU graphic chipset :facepalm: . Since then I tried different drivers among the options proposed in the "Software and Updates" menu, but the issue remains the same : whenever my screen turns off and my pc goes to sleeping mode, if I touch the keyboard or mouse, the screen will wake up on a black screen with just a lil white bar in the top left corner but nothing more to do...

I want to know which driver I should use or if the problem has got nothing to do with that.

I know that this is probably a stupid question, but we all start somewhere !!

Thank you for your time...

(PS: I'm french, sorry for my language )

Comment: The driver to use is the recommended one in the Additional Drivers list. And you have to disable Secure Boot. And use the Nvidia X Server Settings app to select Nvidia (High Performance) and reboot to make it effective.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't have anything anything "recommended" among the Nvidia drivers, but one is marked as "tested", I guess it's the right one... Btw the "high performance" thing is in Nvidia's OpenGL settings so does this performance profile only change things for OpenGL ? ( I know it sounds stupid ahah )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)