# How to set up a nvidia driver in Ubuntu properly?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I want to change my driver in Ubuntu 22.04.1 from x.org X server to the nvidia-driver-525. But every time I reboot the system to apply the nvidia driver the graphic user interface is kind of zoomed in or rather not scaled correctly.
Does anyone had a similar problem and know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you just change the display resolution in "Displays" in Settings?  Once it's changed to the correct resolution it should remain there until it's changed again.  Or perhaps I am not correctly understanding your question.

Comment: Well, technically it works like that, but when I use the nvidia-driver-525 its "stuck" in the 640x480(4:3) resolution and I can't change it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)