# Installing NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have followed a number of tutorials to install NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 22.04, but none has worked so far. Before the update, on Ubuntu 20.04, everything worked fine.

I have tried to install the driver via GUI and console as well.
In the console, I have tried to install versions nvidia-driver-525, nvidia-driver-470, and nvidia-driver-515-open by running

```
sudo apt install [driver version]
```

I have RTX2080Ti.

If I run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, I get the following error:

```
dpkg: warning: version 'unsigned-5.18.10-051810' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
dpkg: warning: version 'unsigned-5.18.10-051810' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
dpkg: warning: version 'unsigned-5.18.10-051810' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
dpkg: warning: version 'unsigned-5.18.10-051810' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 432, in autoinstall
    command_install(config)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
    UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Comment: Try at the command line, sudo apt install nvidia-driver-XXX nvidia-dkms-XXX
where XXX is the desired driver. Reboot once installed.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is a fresh install and logged in Ubuntu on Xorg (from settings icon in log in)

do the following:

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

just to get any updates, then from this github page https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md

The following command is what you run to install the nvidia drivers (version 515***; change this to the latest one for your nvidia card; consult the page for more info)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-515 libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386
```

then reboot with

```
reboot
```

Hope this works and check to make sure your OS recognizes your GPU.