# How to install Nvidia drivers on laptop with integrated AMD Radeon graphics?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, radeon

I have a Lenovo Legion S7-15ACH6 laptop, Type 82K8 with discrete NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 and integrated AMD Radeon graphics cards. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and want to installed NVIDIA drivers, but have issues.
I installed nvidia-prime (after all I realized that it is for Intel integrated graphics) and tried to install nvidia-drivers.

After rebooting the laptop did not boot. I even can not open terminal with alt + shift + f1 or alt + shift + f3 to uninstall the drivers.

So the only way is to install Ubuntu again to fix this.

So how to install Nvidia drivers on laptop with integrated amd graphics?

I installed `NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage from nvidia-driver-525-open(proprietary, tested)` from the Software and Updates app.

Available drivers to install:

[image: available drivers to install]

I a found way to get the machine to boot. Open the terminal pressing the power button and Shift after that I ran in the terminal `sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` and the laptop boots.

Comment: It would help to know what driver you installed and how. As for the only way to fix have you tried booting from the live media? If you can a simple change to a different driver may be all you need. Since you have not given the details that is only a guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Comment: Unfortunately do not answer. The same problem(