# gvfs-backends unmet dependency

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, dependencies

I by mistake un-installed ubuntu software center and gvf packages, when i am trying to install gvf packages i get this error.

I ran  `sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gvfs-backends : Depends: gvfs (= 1.20.2-1ubuntu3.1) but 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: gvfs-daemons (= 1.20.2-1ubuntu3.1) but 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: gvfs-libs (= 1.20.2-1ubuntu3.1) but 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: gvfs-common (= 1.20.2-1ubuntu3.1) but 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to fix all this ?

Comment: You tried to install a package that has Ubuntu 14.10 dependencies in Ubuntu 14.04 which resulted in an `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages` error message. Please check that your repositories are the defaults for your system by comparing them with [What is the correct output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/q/443036/).