# Ubuntu Software only lists installed programs

Tags: 18.04, software-center

**DISCLAIMER**: I'm brand new to Ubuntu, and I have zero coding experience, so please keep any answers in layman's terms.

I was browsing the Ubuntu Software store thingy (Software Center? Ubuntu Software? wtf is it called) to look for programs to download. When I go to browse, however, it only lists programs I have installed. I've tried to look up answers to this issue, but I can't understand any of the solutions posted since it's almost all in code or in extremely technical jargon I just don't understand. Could someone that knows their stuff please help a newbie out? I don't even have any idea where to start, so please explain to me what I need to do.

Nothing is missing when I go into the Ubuntu Software. It's only when I go to browse the different categories where it only shows what I have installed. I can still utilize the search feature to find specific programs, but as you can imagine I can't get all that far using just that if I don't know what's out there.

I've restarted my computer and it didn't do anything to fix it.

Comment: updated. this is not my issue.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: given that i just installed ubuntu on this laptop earlier today, it's whatever version this currently is. 18.04 iirc

Comment: @weasel If you mean the newest version, then yes, 18.04. But 16.04 and 14.04 are still supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the menu bar at the top of Ubuntu Software click *All* in order to show all software, not just installed software.

Open the terminal and upgrade the list of available software by running these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories are missing from the sources.list file at `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you can replace it with a standard Ubuntu 18.04 sources list like in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443036/what-is-the-correct-output-of-cat-etc-apt-sources-list/443075#443075). Make sure to run this command after changing sources.list to refresh the list of available software.

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: the menu bar works normally in that regard, but it's sadly not that simple. when I click on "All," it shows me the front page of the store. but when I go to browse (e.g. recommended graphics/audio & video/etc. applications), it just shows me what I have installed in those tags.

Comment: that most recent edit fixed it! thanks a ton <3