# Ubuntu 19.04 trouble running apt update

Tags: apt

I am trying to install phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 19.04 and got myself in the following trouble. Can anyone help me with it?

My question is different from all the questions some guys are referring to. I am not sure where they found similarity but by looking at their question my question is certainly different.

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease               
Hit:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:8 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                         
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Hit:10 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease             
Err:11 http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu disco InRelease                    
  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
Err:12 http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
Err:13 http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

This is the output of command `sudo apt-get update`

```
Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Hit:3 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]     
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu disco InRelease               
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                         
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release         
Err:12 http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu disco InRelease                    
  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
Err:13 http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
Err:14 http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
Fetched 97.5 kB in 16s (6,182 B/s)                        
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 202.141.176.110 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Can you please share the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I'd suggest switching mirrors; I didn't work out which it is on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors it is (ie. is it maintained well, or last-update so far gone it's counter-overflowed (thus unknown), but I'm getting errors on it too [University of Science and Technology of China, in browser]

Comment: @beingadityak I have added the output of this command in my question.

Comment: @guiverc I am also sure that I need to switch those mirror links. As they are not working now. But I am not sure how to do it and which links to replace with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install PhpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161880/unable-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-19-04)

Comment: @fkraiem It doesn't look like a duplicate as the issue for the OP is with the mirrors' URL

Comment: To change mirror, please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  (*Download Server* section, the picture will look somewhat like the image just under CD-ROM/DVD title in the "Download from:")

Answer (score 1):

I found that my `sources.list` had some source links that were no longer exists. They were added during my attempt to install other software. So when every time I was trying to run an update system wasn't able to fetch the necessary packages.

I was able to resolve the issue using the answer on this post  [by replacing the sources list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140461/ubuntu-19-04-incorrect-sources-list?answertab=active#tab-top)

Now, my issue is fixed and I am able to install the other software.