# How to solve unmet dependency because of broken package?

Tags: mysql, php, laravel

(*I **just** moved from ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.*)

## What I can't understand

- The process of how I got to the problem and the detailes are explained below, but I genuinely don't understand the part where it says

---

```
php7.4-mysql : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.2) but 7.4.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

- I can understand that the package `php7.4-mysql` dependes `on php7.4-common` (which is installed, so I don't see the problem there), but it also says `(= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.2)` and then I'm lost... 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.2? WHAT IS THAT? and if that is not complicated enough it adds... `but 7.4.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` and then I just can't figure out how to move past this.

---

## More insight

- I know a similar questions has been asked, I've read them and the solutions posted don't seem to fix my problem.
  I'm trying to use the `$ php artisan migrate` command in a production environment of my own (I hired a hosting and I'm just messing around with it), and I get the output...

---

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = gastigram and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

      +34 vendor frames 
  35  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

- I googled it and they say is a problem with a missing driver, makes sense... it says right there missing driver, so I tried to install the php7.4-mysql driver but then...

---

```
$ sudo apt install php7.4-mysql 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-mysql : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.2) but 7.4.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this problem with the unmet dependency because of a broken package?

## Getting help

- I run `$ apt-cache policy php7.4-common` as @guiverc suggested

---

This is the output

```
php7.4-common:
  Installed: 7.4.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 7.4.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 7.4.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.4.3-4ubuntu2.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.4.3-4ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Hi @guiverc I **just** moved from ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. (updated my question)

Comment: Can you add a `apt-cache policy php7.4-common` as it looks like you've added 3rd party sources that weren't built for *focal*/20.04  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php7.4-common

Comment: I just updated my question with the output @guiverc I must say you seem to found out so easily were the problem was!

Comment: I don't think so @karel

Comment: Why should I restore my default repositories? which ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/) and [What is the correct output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/q/443036).

Comment: I've seen other questions asking something similar to "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages" I checked those as I said, and they don't show a similar output

Comment: @karel I already got a new sources.list, the problem is not there, I don't think it is, I did what those answers say, still can't pass the problem

Comment: The results of `apt-cache policy php7.4-common` clearly show that php7.4-common was not installed from the standard Ubuntu sources.list. It was installed from a PPA , so you must **remove php7.4-common** and update with `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Still `$php artisan migrate` gives me the `Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = gastigram and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')` output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## I just removed the package that seemed to have problems!

```
$ sudo apt remove php7.4-common
```

Then I installed it again, after that I just tried the same command again, and *voila*!

I must say that I did check the posts that @Karel suggested and created a new sources.list file the way the answers to those questions suggested, and it worked, it might had something to do with that as well... honestly I didn't try what solved my problem before (that is uninstalling php7.4-common; cause I didn't really understand what the os was telling me), so I don't know if creating the new file with the changes in software & updates helped or not.

Comment: FYI: If you look at the `apt-cache` output you provided, you'd installed a later version back on 18.04, which stopped the official *focal* (20.04) version from being installed. `apt` and package tools are built to upgrade to the latest version (7.4.9 > 7.4.3) so the correct 20.04/focal version wouldn't install. The `apt-cache` you provided didn't include a source for it (so that source had been removed during upgrade probably thus no source is listed in "***" section), thus when removed; and re-installed it installed the latest available (which then was 7.4.3 intended for *focal* (20.04).

Comment: @guiverc what is in "**" section (are we talking about sources.list)?

I had the 7.4.9 installed, and are you saying that the latest version for focal is 7.4.3... why is that? 

so I went backwards to a compatible version and that fixed that part of the issue?

I already solved both of the problems and could run `$php artisan migrate` (I'm really new at laravel, but my db is in production and working alright), I had to do a couple of things, it wasn't easy at all for a newbie like myself!

Thanks for all the helped I had no idea about this kind of things...

Comment: sorry I'm rushed for time (it should have been '\*\*\*')... In your above post there is "**** 7.4.9-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1*" which doesn't include a http: line like following, meaning you have no source for it anymore (ie. it was downloaded & installed manually, OR my guess was the *release-upgrade* disabled the PPA it came from as it does that).  The official package is the 7.4.3 listed in the URL in my *now* first comment, which matches your `apt-cache` output too meaning you sources are *up-to-date*. My prior comment was for information/learning purposes only.

Comment: @guiverc I asked for information/learning purposes only :-) I actually installed that manually, so you guessed right ;-) THANKS! it was very informative!

Comment: I have also gone through the issue. Now working after applying your solution. Thanks!!