# The following packages have unmet dependencies: libparted-fs-resize0 : Depends: libparted2(=3.4-2build1) but 3.5-3 is installed

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I was upgrading my Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.04 bcz it very glithy and used to freeze very frequently. During the upgrading process some errors occurred and I was left with white screen with "Oh! no something went wrong" message in the middle of the screen . After going to the tty console and trying to do the process again I am facing the following problem :

You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

The following packages have unmet dependencies: libparted-fs-resize0 : Depends: libparted2(=3.4-2build1) but 3.5-3 is installed

parted : Depends: libparted2(=3.4-2build1) but 3.5-3 is installed

I am trying the apt --fix-broken install command but their is of no help.

With 2 days of continuous trying ,miraculously the upgrade resumed and my OS upgraded to 23.04.

But the problems remains the same.

Trying the "sudo apt-get upgrade" command ,it shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libparted-fs-resize0 : Depends: libparted2 (= 3.4-2build1) but 3.5-3 is installed
 parted : Depends: libparted2 (= 3.4-2build1) but 3.5-3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Now when I try "sudo apt --fix-broken install" or "sudo apt install -f" , I get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acpi-support acpid apturl apturl-common breeze-icon-theme g++-11 gcc-12-base:i386
  gedit gedit-common genisoimage gir1.2-gtksource-4 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0
  gir1.2-snapd-1 gnome-bluetooth gnome-bluetooth-common libabsl20210324 libamtk-5-0
  libamtk-5-common libatk1.0-data libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56
  libbpf0 libcamel-1.2-63 libcolord-gtk1 libcupsfilters1 libdav1d5 libdazzle-1.0-0
  libdazzle-common libdns-export1110 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20
  libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1
  libedataserver-1.2-26 libedataserverui-1.2-3 libflac8 libfontembed1
  libfreerdp-client2-2 libgeocode-glib0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgs9-common
  libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtksourceview-4-0 libgtksourceview-4-common libgupnp-1.2-1
  libgweather-3-16 libgweather-common libicu70 libilmbase25 libisc-export1105
  libkf5idletime5 libldap-2.5-0 libmozjs-91-0 libmpdec3 libnautilus-extension1a
  libobjc-11-dev libopenexr25 libopenh264-6 libpcre3 libperl5.34 libpoppler118
  libpostproc55 libprotobuf23 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
  libqpdf28 libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze librest-0.7-0
  librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2
  libsnapd-glib1 libsrt1.4-gnutls libstdc++-11-dev libswresample3 libswscale5
  libtepl-6-2 libtepl-common libtiff5 libvncserver1 libx264-163 libzxingcore1
  nautilus-share perl-modules-5.34 python3-gi-cairo python3-macaroonbakery
  python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons python3-rfc3339 python3-tz python3.10
  python3.10-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libparted-fs-resize0 parted
Suggested packages:
  libparted-dev parted-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libparted-fs-resize0 parted
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/79.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 92.2 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libreoffice-style-elementary' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxklavier16:amd64' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-graphene-1.0:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgavl2:amd64' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'printer-driver-pxljr' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libavc1394-0:amd64' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblwp-protocol-https-perl' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblmdb0:amd64' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-more-itertools' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'aspell' missing; assuming package has no files
 currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'usbmuxd' missing; assuming package has no file
s currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'kerneloops' missing; assuming package has no f
iles currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxt6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no
 files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librygel-renderer-2.6-2:amd64' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librygel-db-2.6-2:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-html5lib' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-norasi' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmtdev1:amd64' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-beng' missing; assuming package has no f
iles currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx265-199:amd64' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwpg-0.3-3:amd64' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmhash2:amd64' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtimedate-perl' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-smc-suruma' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libutempter0:amd64' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcollection4:amd64' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwww-robotrules-perl' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libatk1.0-data' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librygel-core-2.6-2:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsepol1:amd64' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'printer-driver-splix' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgail18:amd64' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libao4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no
 files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libvidstab1.1:amd64' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sassc' missing; assuming package has no files 
currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'alsa-topology-conf' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librsync2:amd64' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cpu-checker' missing; assuming package has no 
files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libparted-fs-resize0:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblqr-1-0:amd64' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sound-theme-freedesktop' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ubuntu-report' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnsl-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libasyncns0:amd64' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwildmidi2:amd64' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxshmfence1:amd64' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgtk2.0-bin' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopenh264-6:amd64' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libusbmuxd6:amd64' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-polkit-1.0' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libavfilter7:amd64' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xserver-xorg-video-vesa' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-defer' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-guru-extra' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xml-core' missing; assuming package has no fil
es currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libzxingcore1:amd64' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ipxe-qemu' missing; assuming package has no fi
les currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxxhash0:amd64' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexttextcat-data' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libuchardet0:amd64' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'jq' missing; assuming package has no files cur
rently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdazzle-common' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnsl2:amd64' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnsl2:i386' missing; assuming package has no
 files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libabw-0.1-1:amd64' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-liberation' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-garuda' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cups-pk-helper' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmpdec3:amd64' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lao' missing; assuming package has no fi
les currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libepubgen-0.1-1:amd64' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'x11-utils' missing; assuming package has no fi
les currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'hunspell-en-us' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgtop-2.0-11:amd64' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmd4c0:amd64' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libreoffice-style-yaru' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdca0:amd64' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdotconf0:amd64' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'printer-driver-ptouch' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libefivar1:amd64' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'build-essential' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dc' missing; assuming package has no files cur
rently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'wbritish' missing; assuming package has no fil
es currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopenal-data' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libthai-data' missing; assuming package has no
 files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms' missing; assum
ing package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-json-1.0:amd64' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libavcodec58:amd64' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-knda' missing; assuming package has no f
iles currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjson-glib-1.0-common' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libswscale5:amd64' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sgml-data' missing; assuming package has no fi
les currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgtk2.0-common' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-loma' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libref-array1:amd64' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtiff5:amd64' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-orya-extra' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-droid-fallback' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'usb-modeswitch' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxss1:amd64' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxkbfile1:amd64' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'tnftp' missing; assuming package has no files 
currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgexiv2-2:amd64' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-teluguvijayam' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'policykit-desktop-privileges' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgamin0' missing; assuming package has no fi
les currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdav1d5:amd64' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libiscsi7:amd64' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdbusmenu-qt5-2:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libieee1284-3:amd64' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgraphene-1.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'i965-va-driver:amd64' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libvorbisenc2:amd64' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libodfgen-0.1-1:amd64' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-typewriter' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdvdnav4:amd64' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxres1:amd64' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgdata22:amd64' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgeocode-glib0:amd64' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'laptop-detect' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xcursor-themes' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libicu70:amd64' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaa1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no
 files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'pptp-linux' missing; assuming package has no f
iles currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tibetan-machine' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'librygel-server-2.6-2:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-telu-extra' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstartup-notification0:amd64' missing; assum
ing package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgupnp-1.2-1:amd64' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 217436 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../parted_3.5-3_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'parted' missing; assuming package has no
 files currently installed
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/parted' not owned by package 'parted:
amd64'
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'parted' missing; assuming package has no
 files currently installed
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/parted/changelog.Debian.gz' not owned
 by package 'parted:amd64'
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'parted' missing; assuming package has no
 files currently installed
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/parted/copyright' not owned by packag
e 'parted:amd64'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: directory '/usr/share/doc/parted' contains files not owned
 by package parted:amd64, cannot switch to symlink
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/parted_3.5-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new parted package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libparted-fs-resize0_3.5-3_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'libparted-fs-resize0:amd64' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libparted-fs-resize0' not owned by pa
ckage 'libparted-fs-resize0:amd64'
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'libparted-fs-resize0:amd64' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libparted-fs-resize0/changelog.Debian
.gz' not owned by package 'libparted-fs-resize0:amd64'
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'libparted-fs-resize0:amd64' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libparted-fs-resize0/copyright' not o
wned by package 'libparted-fs-resize0:amd64'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: directory '/usr/share/doc/libparted-fs-resize0' contains f
iles not owned by package libparted-fs-resize0:amd64, cannot switch to symlink
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libparted-fs-resize0_3.5-3_amd64.de
b (--unpack):
 new libparted-fs-resize0:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error 
exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/parted_3.5-3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libparted-fs-resize0_3.5-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When i try "sudo dpkg --configure -a" command, I get :

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.06-2ubuntu16) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 20
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.191~) | grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.191~) | base-files (<< 12.3); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.
  Version of base-files on system is 12.3ubuntu2.
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) | grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.37-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
```

Also, i use ubuntu on a dual boot, the other OS being windows 11.

I am not able to understand what i need to do.Please help me and also ignore my english if their is any errors since I am not very fluent in it.Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 23.04, you should only have software sources for 23.04, otherwise if you mix software sources of different Ubuntu versions you will create a Franken-Debian  OS that is hard to manage its packages properly.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this. i didn't understand what i am doing wrong and what i need to do ???

Comment: libparted-fs-resize0 : Depends: libparted2 (= 3.4-2build1) (from Ubuntu 22.04) but 3.5-3 (from Ubuntu 23.04) is installed. You are running Ubuntu 23.04, so everything should match to 23.04 including your software sources. That's what you should fix first.

Comment: so can u please tell me how should i fix it. i am new linux user i dont understand these things in depth. can u please tell me which commands should run???

Comment: Either [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/) or [What is the correct output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/q/443036/)