# Unknown Other Software link

Tags: updates, update-manager

When I open Software&Updates and Other Software tab, I see a line starts with `https://bearer:mAgJOEWNBZFpEcn.....`.

I disabled this, but I can't understand what is this. Does anyone see something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) and [What is the correct output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/q/443036/) This questionable line is not in your default software sources, so caution is advised. Comment out the questionable line or delete it entirely.

Comment: I see. It seems supicious to me, too. Thanks