# why doesnt the debian goodies command function despite it being reccommended

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, repository

Despite `debian-goodies` being recommended by my console and even being brought up by the console, the error I keep receiving is as follows:

```
E: Unable to locate package debian-goodies
```

The command I am running (the command the console recommended and also on the Ubuntu website) is:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-goodies
```

It appears `debian-goodies` has been either retired or something else as its clearly not able to be found. That's the only package that's not resolving. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.

Comment: `debian-goodies` is available in 22.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=debian-goodies&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all have you checked your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file includes the relevant repository?

Comment: Whilst on my 22.04 using `sudo apt -y install debian-goodies` didn't find it, using `synaptic` did.

Comment: Please read the heredoc description in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/443075/