# Can I remove a virus in Windows from Ubuntu in a dual-boot setup?

Tags: dual-boot, malware

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8 installed on my system. I was doing a clean up on my friend's USB pen drive, which he said had lots of viruses on it. I have Wine installed on my system, and I happened to double click on an exe file -which *I knew* was a virus- out of curiosity. And it seems that the virus has infected many crucial Windows files, which makes it difficult for me to boot to Windows now. Is there any way I can do a safe clean up from Ubuntu? I would have removed and reinstalled Windows using the Ubuntu installer if I could but I don't have the Windows installer program.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes!

You can clean windows viruses from Ubuntu without booting into your Windows.

But I am not sure this would help you as you said you can't boot into windows anymore. But worth trying :)

There are many such antivirus software available, one of them which I prefer is: **ClamAV**

You can install [ClamAV [image: Install clamav]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clamav) via Terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

(**Its also available in Software Center**)

And you can Install clamtk (for graphical interface) from the deb file here: 
[**Dave M
clamtk**](https://bitbucket.org/dave_theunsub/clamtk/downloads/clamtk_5.00-1_all.deb)

While installing, select the version v5.09 (trusty-backports)

**Or** you can install it using the following commands: (but here it is Outdated)

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landronimirc/clamtk -y
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
> ```

After Installing , Update Virus Definitions : `sudo freshclam`

Then search for clamtk in your dash and you will get it.

**Note** : you might need to enable “backports” repository to get updates, so follow : [How do I enable the “backports” repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository)

## you can try Avast!

> 1. Download the .deb file of avast linux edition from here : [avast Linux Home Edition](http://avast-linux-home-edition.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/download)
> 2. Install it : just double click on the *.deb file and you can install it.
> 3. Register for free **1 year** license her : [Avast Registration](https://www.avast.com/registration-free-antivirus.php)
> 4. Launch and scan your files!

You can get lot of similar [anti viruses for Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus) .

As GSM-S said, you might have to boot into any Windows installation Media and try "repair my computer"

**Suggestion :**   Don't play with viruses out of curiosity!

Comment: This Video might help you too [nixie pixel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h3q5ss40oY)

Answer (score 0):

Try an antivirus on ubuntu. Then run the repair disc that came with Windows 8.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus