# how I can fix "AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors."?"

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates

I executed `apt update` as root, but I received this error message:
`AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.` I have found this link that offer a solution editing this config file: `/usr/share/app-info/xmls/org.freedesktop.fwupd.xml`. But I have opened this and I found that I have the same code as solution.[My config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtttc.png)

Can I update my packages with this issue?
EDIT: Full log from shell:

```
Des:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Obj:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Des:3 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Des:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [67,0 kB]
Des:5 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Des:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [38,3 kB]
Des:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [19,4 kB]
Des:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [25,6 kB]
Des:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Des:10 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [293 kB]
Des:11 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [182 kB]
Des:12 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [119 kB]
Des:13 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [132 kB]
Des:14 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.520 B]
Des:15 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [208 B]
Des:16 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Des:17 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [212 B]
Descargados 1.186 kB en 1s (851 kB/s)                        
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Todos los paquetes están actualizados.
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The bug has been fixed in `appstream` package version `0.10.1`, but the version that gets installed in Ubuntu 16.04 is `0.9.4` by default. Ubuntu 16.10 automatically receives the update as it's provided in its standard repositories.

The updated package version with the bugfix for Ubuntu 16.04 however is only provided through the `xenial-backports` repository, which has a lower priority than the others. This means it won't upgrade to this version unless you manually specify it.

To enable the `xenial-backports` repository in first place, follow [How do I enable the "backports" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25717/367990) (but only enable the repository, you don't need to modify the repo priority).

After that, upgrade to the version from `xenial-backports` by typing:

```
sudo apt install appstream/xenial-backports
```

Now your `appstream` package should be upgraded to version `0.10.1`.

```
$ appstreamcli --version
AppStream CLI tool version: 0.10.1
```

Now force refreshing the cache data, you should no longer see any warning:

```
$ sudo appstreamcli refresh --force
AppStream cache update completed successfully.
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting with last command this message: "AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml. " AppStream CLI tool version: 0.10.6

Comment: @JIV I think you should ask a new question about that. You can include a link to this for providing context.

Comment: I am first time experiencing this issue on Ubuntu 16.04 after using it for a few years. Having the same error even though backport repository is enabled. Just post this [question](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2396283&p=13783551#post13783551).

Comment: @JIV, did you post a question for "AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml. " I have the same msg as you. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I did just now - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057791/apt-update-failing-after-updating-appstream

Comment: this was an issue for me as well. i did as described by you but now i get the following error
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadaten-Dateien haben Fehler: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml

how do i fix it? is there a cache to clear or file to delete?

Comment: Even today on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS `appstreamcli` was on version `0.9.4` after executing above it's been upgraded to `0.10.6`

Answer (score 8):

See here, fix currently in progress - 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1644498

Answer (score 6):

The bugs has been [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1644498/comments/25) per 1 December, in order to get rid the bugs, you have to enable `proposed` repository under developer options on Software & Updates.

- Open dash then type "Software & Updates".
- Navigate to "Developer Options" tab.
- Enable "Pre-release updates (xenial-proposed)" checkbox.
- Changing repository setting required admin password, fill it on pop up.
- Close the window then, click <kbd>Reload</kbd> to apply changed source (Equivalent to `apt-get update`).
- Open terminal then try `sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: Thanks Liso, but it seems the proposed fix has now been deployed (possibly within just the last hour or two), because the error just disappeared for me a few minutes ago after I did the standard apt-get update/upgrade procedure.

Comment: Enabling `proposed` and upgrading dumbly from it  can cause lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using a **target release** cause such problems, consider removing it if you have one. It should be in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/<filename>`, and looks something like `APT::Default-Release "n=stretch,o=Debian"`