# What does the apt update error mean?

Tags: apt, updates, appstream

After running "sudo apt update" it seems to work but I get this error "AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors."

What does it mean?
ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]       
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [518 kB]
Get:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [803 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [456 kB]
Get:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [733 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [222 kB]    
Get:10 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [331 kB]        
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [67.7 kB]         
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [68.0 kB]                                                                                                                         
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [107 kB]                                                                                                                   
Get:14 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [318 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [142 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:16 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [228 kB]                                                                                                                         
Get:17 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [640 kB]                                                                                                                         
Get:18 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [584 kB]                                                                                                                          
Get:19 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [246 kB]                                                                                                                  
Get:20 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [331 kB]                                                                                                                     
Get:21 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [16.4 kB]                                                                                                                      
Get:22 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.5 kB]                                                                                                                       
Get:23 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,964 B]                                                                                                               
Get:24 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,324 B]                                                                                                                   
Get:25 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,100 B]                                                                                                               
Fetched 6,165 kB in 12s (495 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                 
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show us a complete apt update (the entire output), including this message? Context matters.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the error message you provided in SE's search bar. It points to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854168/how-i-can-fix-appstream-cache-update-completed-but-some-metadata-was-ignored-d). IOW, this question *seems* to be a duplicate (but I'm not yet qualified to mark it so.) The top voted answers seem to resolve this issue as well.

My answer is this: **Please check out the linked question thread above, and let us know how it went resolving your issue. Good luck!**

Answer (score -1):

The answers provided in that duplicate question are convoluted and require following conditional steps in yet other questions. The answer is to enter this, and only this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install appstream/xenial-backports
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

That is all you need to do.
I will add my answer to the duplicate question.

Edit: make sure the line
`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu release-backports main restricted
 universe multiverse`
is in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and doesn't have a hashtag in front of it. It should already be good, but just check.

Comment: Please do not post duplicated answers. I suggest deleting this one and posting on the dupe.

Comment: That said, this quite literally what [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/859116/158442) suggests. And OP may still need to enable backports as given in that answer.