# Apt update failing after updating appstream

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, appstream

this issue is linked to [how I can fix "AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors."?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854168/how-i-can-fix-appstream-cache-update-completed-but-some-metadata-was-ignored-d)
I had similar problem as described in issue and the approved solution stated that we should update appstream to version 0.10.1+
But after updating to version 0.10.6 I am getting this error regularly after `apt get update` command

> AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata
>   files have
>   errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml Reading package lists...
>   Done E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if
>   /usr/bin/test
>   -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-ca
>   che > /dev/null; fi'

all I have to do is run `apt get update` again and it works. How to solved this?

```
 cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
```

Update 23/07/2018 
Actually its happening still again. Reinstalling didnt helped. Also tried purge:

> apt-get purge libappstream3

But still same error.

Comment: Ok I used `sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream4`, will see if helps

Comment: I had to use `sudo apt install --reinstall libappstream3` instaed, that worked.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as such.

Comment: The same as this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/library-corruption-error-during-apt-get-update/944156#944156

Comment: @fkraiem: I thought question will be closed? Can I close it?

Comment: @JIV It is not closed now,; it may or may not be closed in the future. You can't close it yourself, but maybe you can delete it.