# Metadata and appstream Error while Updating

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, appstream

I am getting an error while updating as a root. After Update log below error was shown in terminal.

```
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/859116/728454) answer and executed `sudo apt install appstream/xenial-backports`.

My `appstream` package is already updated:-

```
$ appstreamcli --version
AppStream CLI tool version: 0.10.6
```

After, force refreshing the cache data. I am getting the following error:-

```
$ sudo appstreamcli refresh --force
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seemed to be an xml error in line 265 of file `/var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml` mentioned in the metadata error output.

Change `Firmware_SF30&SN30` to `Firmware_SF30&amp;SN30`